# Why is a spliced USB extension cable frying USB Drives?

Tags: usb, low-voltage, data-storage

I cut a functional USB-A extension cable in half, reconnected the wires, and plugged a USB drive into it. This cable killed three USB Storage Drives. Why?

[image]

The above photo shows the cable. I know, I know it's not an ideal cable. I was [testing something that wasn't working](https://melanienallen.wordpress.com/2023/03/26/usb-cord-you-mystery/), so I removed what I was testing and just tried to reconnect the cable back to itself. Without the shielding and twisted pairs, I would expect either:

1. Some data corruption may occur or
2. It just wouldn't work at all

But what actually happened (when I plugged the male-end of the USB extension cable into a laptop computer's USB port and I plugged a functional USB storage drive into the female end of the USB extension cable) was that the USB storage drive died. I thought I was going crazy, so I reproduced it with another. And another.

Three times in a row this cable rendered a functional USB drive no longer functional. How is that possible?

And by "no longer functional" I mean that `dmesg` on Linux shows zero activity when it's plugged-in now. It's just dead. Oh, and there was no smoke or smells or sound or anything indicating a short or something bad.

This is a low-voltage cable. We're talking USB-A here (as opposed to USB-C). There is no auxiliary power. Power was provided by an ordinary laptop computer. Obviously the USB Storage were powered by the computer (not the other way around).

I would expect this awful cable to maybe cause some radio interference. Maybe some data corruption. But I have no idea how it could consistently kill USB Drives.

Why did this cable kill my USB Storage Drives?

Comment: Perhaps voltage spikes due to the high inductance on the signal lines?

Comment: @Bryan The Op wrote "so I removed what I was testing and just tried to reconnect the cable back to itself" indicating the two ends were from the same cable. Unless he was mistaken, your comment isn't applicable.

Comment: What do you even mean by a storage drive? A USB hard disk or USB flash stick? If a hard disk, did it have external power? Why leave the shield disconnected?

Comment: It's a complete guess, but maybe with no shield you have a lot more ground resistance and therefore ground bounce, possibly this in combination with the degraded Zo of the pairs leads to overshoot on signal lines killing IO ports? You could join the shield and try to fry another one ... or connect the old one and start looking with a scope.

Comment: It sounds as if 5V (from VBUS) was delivered to one of the data lines. That would easily fry the USB chip as the data lines use 3.3V only. Have you measured if there is a short between some of the wires?

Comment: @Justme as stated in the question, there is no auxiliary power. The USB Storage drive is a small USB-A thumb drive. It does not supply power.

Comment: @Codo you can clearly see from the photo that there is no short. Each wire was taped-down very far from one another to prevent this.

Comment: Have you measured it? The short could be where you cut back the isolation or in some other place you don't expect.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to measure a short. I have a multi meter and did a continuity check on the resistance setting. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: What do you mean that the "storage drives" are "killed"? Did you try to plug them into a plain Windows computer? Are all three drives identical (brand, capacity)?